# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot make conection with wifi or ethernet

Tags: networking, internet, netplan

Recently I had to add some files as root to the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ in order tu run a time tracker app, but when I reboot my computer wi-fi and ethernet conection were dropped, doesn't appear in side bar. Already I tried delate the pasted files, editing netplan, booting, and every tutorial related in youtube but the issue persist.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.